# How to send push notifications to multiple device with FCM tokens using cloud functions

Tags: android, node.js, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

First I generated a FCM token and stored in firestore. After that I wrote a cloud functions to send notifications based on FCM token. and I deployed cloud functions it says successfully sent notifications with status ok. But it doesn't displays in mobile device. My Index.js is

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const Firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const firestore = new Firestore();
const db = admin.firestore();
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.hellouser = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{token}')
    .onWrite(event =>{
    var document = event.data.data();
    console.log("tokens",document); 
    var token = ['cdNN0AbYKU0:APA91bEyL0zo3zwHZD8H43Vp7bxAfYgehlVI8LrKktPO2eGuByVDdioysIGxHe5wocwq8ynxRToJPpOve_M59YY_MIRbWLnF9AIgoTwJORXZbw6VBw7']// this is my FCM token.
    if(
    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: "Message",
            body: "hi hello",
            sound: "default"
        }
    };
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload).then((response)=> {

    console.info("Successfully sent notification")
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.warn("Error sending notification " , error)
    });
});
```

How to send notifications based on the  FCMtoken.

Comment: anybody please help and guide me.

Comment: did you find solution for it?

Answer (score 3):

If it's the exact code you use then check syntax near `if(`. This may help you.
Next write some code to go through your `response` object. Firebase may take your tokens and payload, process them and return 200 OK response but in the response you will have errors. 
Response has general structure like this: 
`{ results: 
   [ { //stuff related to one token },{ //stuff related to one token } ],
  canonicalRegistrationTokenCount: 0,
  failureCount: 1,
  successCount: 0,
  multicastId: SOME_LONG_NUMBER }`
Take in mind that `response.results` array has status of each message sent to token in the same order as tokens in your `token` array.
 You can see all posible errors in [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/errors). 
If `response.failureCount > 0` then no messages were sent and you should get corresponding error in `response.results`.
Also learn about `options` variable. `options.priority` must be `'high'` to guarantee fast message delivery.
 Maybe this will help.